# NLP and spaCy: How to find a similar phrase in a string

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

thanks in advance for reading.

I'm in Python and using spaCy for processing English text. I have a phrase that I want to search for

```
search_phrase = "payment date"
```

in a larger phrase

```
text_to_be_searched = "Party A will pay Party B on the transaction date."
```

And I want the search to match "payment date" with "transaction date" based on similarity.

How can I do this? I don't see an obvious way, and the only thing I can think of is to manually split `text_to_be_searched` into chunks.  One extra difficulty here is that the matching phrases could have different numbers of tokens, so I'd have to break it into chunks of 1, 2, ... 5 tokens and search each chunk in each set of chunks. For clarity, this would be:

Set of 1-token chunks:

```
['Party','A','will', ..., 'date']
```

Set of 2-token chunks:

```
['Party A','A will','will pay', ..., 'transaction date']
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

You can get the word embeddings then find a similarity between them. `spacy` is able to do this as follows. According to the documentation, by default, it is cosine similarity. You need to find an optimum `threshold` value of course.

```py
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
search = nlp("payment date")
text_to_be_searched = nlp("Party A will pay Party B on the transaction date.")
threshold = 0.8

matched_words = []
for token in text_to_be_searched:
    print(token, token.similarity(search))
    if token.similarity(search) > threshold:
        matched_words.append(token)

print(f"\nMatched words: {matched_words}")
```

This prints

```
Party 0.34560599567510353
A 0.2068122164970917
will 0.7228409255656658
pay 0.7228409255656658
Party 0.34560599567510353
B 0.11308183304731666
on 0.20214880588221648
the 0.324707772449963
transaction 0.9999999409847675
date 0.9999999409847675
. 0.2766332837661776

Matched words: [transaction, date]
```

To use the `en_core_web_md`, first you need to download it as follows

```
python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_md
```

To get the word embeddings, you can use different things such as language models like `BERT` etc.

Comment: Thanks! This is great, and is a good first idea. As mentioned in the question, though, this doesn't help with bigrams or n-grams.

Comment: I forgot about it, sorry. May be you can compute the bigrams or n-grams with `nltk` library, then use this approach for each bigarm or n-gram.